# wmd-editor breaks in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, wmd-editor

We have recently started using WMD editor and found that in IE 8, it just goes on increasing the scroll size of the page by simply increasing the size of the textarea endlessly. The only option left is to close the browser after that causing lot of frustration. you can check wmd-editor demo [here](http://wmd-editor.com/demo). does anybody know of any solution to this issue ?

Comment: This is the old script, try with some of the new versions: http://github.com/cky/wmd/tree/master   OR (mine) http://moowmd.awardspace.info/

Answer (score 2):

after a lot of trial & error, we finally found the issue and fixed it ourselves. None of the  parent container of the div in which the wmd editor is placed into should have the css property position defined. else, it will break the editor in IE8.