# WMD Markdown appears broken in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-8, markdown

I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051516/wmd-editor-breaks-in-ie8) on SO (which is exactly the same problem I'm having), but the OP's solution a) doesn't work for me, and b) isn't feasable in my site.

On the [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) project for WMD, it says

> IE8 support is on its way.

My question is, does anyone know how to make WMD Markdown work in IE8 right now? Or does anyone know when the new release might be coming that works with IE8?

I'm willing to put in a little effort here (I don't expect a handout), but my Javascript chops aren't all that great, so I don't even know where to begin.

FYI, here's my current solution which IMO isn't all that elegant

```
        <![if ! IE]>
            <noscript>
        <![endif]>
            <h3>Please use <%: Html.ActionLink("Markdown", "Markdown", "About")%> to style your input.</h3>
        <![if ! IE]>
            </noscript>
        <![endif]>
        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.About, 5, 5, New With {.class = "user-edit-textarea"})%>
        <div class="wmd-preview">
        </div>

<![if ! IE]>
    <script src="../../Assets/Scripts/wmd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]>
```

*note: I tagged this topic with **asp.net-mvc-2** just because of what my markup looks like*

### EDIT:

Further to this issue, if you go to the [official demo page](http://wmd-editor.com/demo), you will see the same behavior (in IE8) as I'm describing in my issue.  This is definitely a bug with WMD Markdown.

I'd like to know how Jeff fixed it on the SO site.

Comment: Do you get any specific errors in IE8 regarding line numbers that you can point out?

Comment: IE8 is not throwing any errors what so ever.

Comment: Nothing seems out of place in fiddler either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it appears as though all Markdown issues in IE8 are fixed if you use [derobins's wmd](http://github.com/derobins/wmd)